# How can I delete all the files one by one after downloading it from the Azure Blob folder using Java

Tags: java, file, azure-blob-storage

I am downloading some files from the Azure blob to my local directory for processing it, and while downloading I need to delete them ***one by one***, so that if for some reason my process fails we can have those files which are not downloaded. I am able to download the files to my local, but when I am trying to delete them from the folder the entire folder is getting deleted. My folder structure is

```
image-source(container name)

    HDF(folder)
    a1.tif
    a2.tif
    a3.tif
    CFO(folder)
    b1.tif
    b2.tif
    JPO(folder)
    h1.tif
    h2.tif
```

image source is the container name under which I have 3 folders, HDF, CFO, JPO, which then contain some image files. I have to delete each image files while downloading it, but in my code the entire folder is also deleted after all the files are gone.

And when I am getting the files from the blob folder they are coming in the format of HDF/a1.tif, HDF/a2.tif

I am posting the code I am using for downloading the image files and also what I am doing to delete them

```
try{
   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorage.parse(storageConnect);
   CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
   CloudBlobContainer myCloudBlobContainer = blobClient.getContainerReference(Constant.Container_Name);
   Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = myCloudBlobContainer.listBlobs();

 for(ListBlobItem blob: blobs){
  if(blob instanceof CloudBlobDirectory){
  CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory) blob;
  Iterable<ListBlobItem> fileBlobs = directory.listBlobs();
  String actualFileName = "";
  String actualDir = "";
  CloudBlob cloudBlob = null;
  for(ListBlobItem fileBlob: fileBlobs){
  if(fileBlob instanceof CloudBlob){
  cloudBlob = (CloudBlob)fileBlob;
   if(cloudBlob.getName().contains(".tif")){
   log.info("File Name with directory: ",cloudBlob.getName());
   actualFileName = cloudBlob.getName().split("/")[1];
   actualDir = cloudBlob.getName().split("/")[0];
   Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(actualDir));
   cloudBlob.download(new FileOutPutStream(actualDir+"\\"+actualFileName));
   log.info("Download File from directory{},actualDir,actualFileName);
   deleteFileAfterDownload(cloudBlob);

  }
 }
}

private void deleteFileAfterDownload(CloudBlob cloudBlob){
 cloudBlob.deleteIfExists();
}
```

After I execute the code, the entire folder along with the files are removed, but I don't want that. I want to delete files one by one and retain the folder as it is.

Answer (score 1):

> After I execute the code, the entire folder along with the files are
> removed, but I don't want that. I want to delete files one by one and
> retain the folder as it is.

Unfortunately, it is not possible with Azure Blob Storage as the folders there are not real folders, they are virtual. If we take the example of your data, the name of the blob is actually `HDF/a1.tif` where `HDF` is the virtual folder. So once you delete all blobs in that virtual folder, that virtual folder is also gone.

If you want proper folder hierarchy, you should take a look at Azure Data Lake Storage (Gen 2) which is built on top of Azure Blob Storage or Azure File Storage. Both of these services has first class support for folders.